# sed replace multiple patterns with certain string

Tags: bash, sed, find-and-replace

I've been tasked with replacing a whole lot of hardcoded ID's in some code (for example: `private static String MERCHANT_ID = "1234";`) with references to a config file somewhere (so the replaced version for this example should be `private static String MERCHANT_ID = ConstantMerchants.MERCHANT_A;`).

The default find and replace function in Eclipse *would* be fine if I were replacing just a few ID's, but I'm not. I have twenty projects, all of them contain hundreds of files with multiple different notations of the old string.

I've already compiled a list of regex patterns that match every possible notation.

Is there a way to use sed to replace all old strings with the new versions by having a configuration file somewhere containing the old pattern, and what it should be replaced with?

I'm looking for something that allows me to define patterns with a new value, think of something similar to this: (but then with quite a few more ID's)

```
# old | new
/merchantId:\s*("|')1234("|'),/|merchantId: ConstantMerchants.MERCHANT_A
/private static String MERCHANT_ID\s*=\s*("|')1234("|');/|private static String MERCHANT_ID = ConstantMerchants.MERCHANT_A
```

If I should use some other tool that'll help me better resolve this issue, I'd love to hear about it. I'd very much like to use the new Bash on Windows feature, but that is only because it looks cool :)

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is: can you not get your REs to work in `sed` syntax, or can you not get `sed` to work on multiple files, or what?

Comment: I can't find how to write a single `sed` command that performs all the replaces, using multiple regex's and files

Comment: In `sed` you can use the `-e` option to make as many substitutions to as many files as you need in a single run, eg `sed -i -e 's/old1/new1/' -e 's/old2/new2' ... file1 file2 ...`. If the files are not all in a single directory or at the same level in a subdirectory tree, allowing you to select them with a wild-card match, you can use `find` and `xargs` to build the run string.

Comment: If you're not too familiar with `sed`, [this](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) is a good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it the problem is that you have a set of syntax patterns to match, and independently a lot of possible numbers that need to be translated, and you need to "multiply" these together.  The following might be a suitable `sed` mechanism, assuming some simplification: in your `sed` first use the patterns to match lines, then use the number conversion on these lines.  Eg create a file `sedscript` holding

```
/merchantId:\s*("|')[0-9]+("|')/b change
/private static String MERCHANT_ID\s*=\s*("|')[0-9]+("|')/b change
b
:change
s/["']1234["']/ConstantMerchants.MERCHANT_A/
s/["']1235["']/ConstantMerchants.MERCHANT_B/
```

It starts with each of your patterns followed by the command `b change` which means branch to the label `change` when the pattern is found. The list of patterns ends with the command `b` which means branch to the end, i.e. move on to read the next input line from the file.

The `:change` means this is the label `change` where we branch to. Then follows each of your possible number to name translations.  The simplification is to assume that only one number in quotes will appear on the line, so we can ignore which actual pattern matched. If there are some exceptions to this, it might be worth handling those by hand.

On a Unix system (I don't know about windows) you could use this shell script to edit the files:

```
find dir -type f |
xargs sed -i -r -f sedscript
```

The `-i` will edit the files in-place, so *always start by copying the files* to a new directory `dir`, then run this command on the copy, and use `diff -ru` between the two directories to verify that it is doing what you want. The `-r` is needed (on Unix) to have GNU sed accept `(a|b)` instead of the usual `\(a\|b\)` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much cleaner solution than the horrors that I came up with so far. I do indeed have only one ID per line at all times. Your solution with the `change` label also helps reduce the number of commands I need to add.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [MAN Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) you'll see that `sed` supports a `-f` parameter to supply a script file. Said file should contain every replace to run as you'd supply it to `sed` directly. So e.g. you'd have:

- `s/old/new/`
- `s/new/old/`

On separate lines in the file and it would apply both commands to whatever you supply by `stdout`. As an example: `echo "old" | sed -f script.file` with the above content would lead to the output old.

To apply said rules to multiple files, one option would be to use a loop in which you run `sed` with the script for each file and save the changes to the file itself. Another would be to use the option `-i` and supply "all" files as command line arguments. Depending on the number you might run into issues with the total length of the command.

Comment: Thanks. I assume it's possible to first run grep to find all files containing a match, and then pipe the output to sed to change them?

Comment: Certainly. You will just have to come up with a script to do that. One possibility would be to run the grep to get the name and compile them into a variable which gets passed as the file parameter for `sed`. I'm certain it's possible to do something like that, just not how.